# What was the earliest movie with a "conspiracy theorist's pegboard"?

Tags: first-appearance

This is about movies that include a character that has a wall or pegboard full of photos and notes, and strings connecting these.

Sometimes the character with this setup might at first seem a bit mentally disturbed (but may eventually be proven right) or a conspiracy theorist, or some lone investigator.

What is the earliest movie showing this "conspiracy theorist's pegboard"?

Comment: Does it have to have the strings?

Comment: thanks, @moviegique, yes I would like to know about the earliest appearance for the version with the strings. Although a "string-less" version would be cool to know **as long as** it belongs to a character that is similar to those that these are nowadays portrayed with.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. I can't find it right now {on mobile) but we have seen this before.

Comment: @Paulie_D I recall that question being closed as "unclear what you're asking". I don't know the procedure here, but on other SEs this question would be left open as it's much clearer.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yeah, I assume the other question has been deleted by the roomba. I'm not convined of the value of the question but it's not close-worthy as it stands.

Comment: It more usually belongs to a detective than a conspiracy theorist.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah, I'm thinking of some '50s gangster stuff but the problem with "earliest" is one hasn't seen ALL the movies, and a great many from the '30s and earlier are missing.

Comment: I thought TV Tropes might solve this one but it's pretty threadbare... http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StringTheory